# Symfony 5 multiple login forms

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony5

I have created a simple Login for admins on my webpage which works very well.
But now I want to have a different login page for Customers integrated in my webpage.
How is it possible to have multiple logins?

All my users are in the "user"-Entity and I am checking the login with E-Mail and Password.

Comment: why would you use a different process to authenticate your customers?

Comment: As Cid said, you can use the same page for both types of users. Or add a additional login page, with similar backend but different frontend targeted for customers, with different URL.

Comment: 2 routes one for admins, one for customers, but the same user provider will be the trick

Answer (score 0):

Just create another route that render the form for users:

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login-user", name="app_login_user")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {

        /* put your logic here to login a user,
           it might be exactly the same as the one you have for admin */

        // render your regular user login page
        return $this->render('security/login_user.html.twig');
    }

   /**
     * @Route("/login-admin", name="app_admin_user")
     */
    public function loginAdmin(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {

        /* logic to login an admin */

        // render your admin login page
        return $this->render('security/login_admin.html.twig');
    }
}
```