# different routes and login interfaces for each user role in symfony 5.4

Tags: authentication, symfony, symfony5, symfony-security

i have two roles in my application one is admin and the other is the mother each role have a different interface i first tried to make the both roles sign in by the same route and same interface and the code works perfectly for both but now that i want to add another route and seperate the users login interfaces  i don't know how to do it any help ?

````
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
class AuthController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'admin_login')]
    public function loginAdmin(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils,Security $security): Response
    {
        $user = $security->getUser();
        if ($user) {
            // Check the role of the user
            if (in_array('ROLE_MOTHER', $user->getRoles())) {
                // If the user is a mother, redirect to another route
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_testTemplate');
            }
           else{
            return $this->redirectToRoute('get_users');
           }
        }
        // Get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // Last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('security/admin_login.html.twig', [
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }
    #[Route('/logout', name: 'app_logout')]
    public function logout(): void
    {
        
    }
}
  ``` this is my controller for handling login and this is my security.yaml file ```                                
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: admin_login
                check_path : admin_login
                enable_csrf: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                target: admin_login
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800
                path: /
                always_remember_me: true
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        #  - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        #  - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_MOTHER}

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
````

Comment: Please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803490/symfony-5-multiple-login-forms